# Get image urls from html stored as string

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, refactoring

I would like to get all image links from the text and save them to a list.Then I have to add a prefix to each src and replace it in the html code. The problem itself is not that difficult, but I wonder how I could do it in a more effective way. If the html code is long, my program takes a long time to run. My current code:

```cs
string html ="<h1>This is heading 1</h1><p>This is another paragraph.</p><a href='https://www.w3schools.com'>This is a link</a><img src='/media/w3schools.jpg' alt='W3Schools.com' width='104' height='142'><h1>This is heading 1</h1><img src='/media/w3schools2.jpg'><p>This is another paragraph.</p><p>This is another paragraph.</p><p>This is another paragraph.</p><h1>This is heading 1</h1><h1>This is heading 1</h1><p>This is another paragraph.</p><a href='https://www.w3schools.com'>This is a link</a><img src='/media/w3schools.jpg' alt='W3Schools.com' width='104' height='142'>";
            
string tempHtml = html;
List<string> imagesUrl = new List<string>();

while (true)
{
  if (!tempHtml.Contains("src"))
  {
    break;
  }

  //get first index of src
  var index = tempHtml.IndexOf("src");

  //get index where image src was started
  var startIndex = index + 5;

  //remove text before image src
  tempHtml = tempHtml.Substring(startIndex, tempHtml.Length-startIndex);

  //find and of image src
  var nextIndex = tempHtml.IndexOf("'");

  //add image src to list
  imagesUrl.Add(tempHtml.Substring(0, nextIndex));

  //get string from end of image src
  tempHtml = tempHtml.Substring(nextIndex,tempHtml.Length-nextIndex);
}

foreach (var item in imagesUrl)
{
   html = html.Replace(item, $"ns.{item}");
}
```

It is possible make code more efficient?

Comment: I recommend that you use an HTML parser, like "dcsoup" https://github.com/piaoye2019/dcsoup to achieve this

Comment: You may also consider looking at [Html Agility Pack](https://html-agility-pack.net/)

Comment: but how and where did the links and information get into that web page in the first place? Surely they are not hard coded? It would see to me that the oringal code that renders the web page has the data source and code that filled out, created, and displayed those links in the first place. Seems to me, you should be going to the code source of the page that renders that information, and thus pull the original data base or information that was being used to render and display that information in the first. That way, no html parsing is required. So were and how did those links get in that page?